# UK - Leak on inlet on toilet cistern - New Parts

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, leak, cistern

few videos and reading the instructions figured replacing the innards on the old flush system we had/ just broke was within my means but I've hit a roadblock.

Currently having a leak from the inlet. Have got all new parts more or less apart from the pipework into the cistern.

Basically I cannot seem to get the seal to be watertight so with water in the cistern there is a drip.

Add to this when connected to the water in pipe at the yellow 15mm connector there is now water leaking from that joint too it seems.

Is this a relatively easy fix or bite the £ bullet and have a plumber fix for me tomorrow?
Pics:
[image][image][image][image][image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that the seal that goes on the threaded portion between its flange and the porcelain (shown as the black ring in the top image) is in good condition - even using a sealer like plumber's mate can help.

Comment: Its brand new and instructions specifically say not to use anything like PTFE tape or plumbers mate ;(.

Comment: That may be so, but what is the condition of the porcelain?

Comment: No expert to say - no cracks or chips I can tell. Ended up having a plumber pop and sort this morning. Fingers crossed no more leaks.